# Insert only if row doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am using PreparedStatement to prepare sql queries. I want to insert a row in table if and only if it doesn't exist.

I tried this -

```
INSERT INTO users (userId) VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userId = ?
```

But this will unnecessarily update the userId.

How can i insert the `userId` here ?

Comment: Let the database return the Exception on duplicate key and handle it.

Comment: The key word you are looking for is `UPSERT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT  INTO users 
        (userId) 
SELECT  ?
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    users 
        where   userId = ?
        )
```

Comment: IDK, but as you are not getting any upvotes i can't figure out which is better approach...your answer or the other one by _RiaD_ ?

Comment: My answer has more complex SQL, RiaD's answer will silently ignore conversion errors.  There's something to be said for both.

Comment: @Andomar . . . I would add in your favor that this is standard SQL.

Comment: OK, Thanks ! i will be using your's

Comment: Just a simple question, is this strategy phantom record safe? If so, please explain how this will behave on parallel execution.

Comment: You'd need to wrap the statement in a "repeatable read" or "serializable" transaction to avoid phantom reads.  [See the MySQL documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: @Andomar I already know that, just wanted to make sure OP (and future readers) also know how to use this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO users (userId) VALUES (?)
```

But you should understand *why* do you want ignore errors.

Comment: I won't recommend ignoring errors. They should be handled instead of being ignored.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I _do_ understand that it usually should be handled. But if you really need do nothing if row exists, are you going to write `catch{do nothing}` block?

Comment: I would handle the Exception. This depends on how the results will affect the application. For example, if a user inputs data and tries to save it, the application should show a message like *Sorry, this is a dup entry* or something (of course, I would use a formal message). If it is for an intern process, I would at least log the exception and then post a strategy about what to do: stop the process, just continue with a warning, etc...

Answer (score 0):

on duplicate key does not work correctly when the table is an innodb. It creates exactly the problem you are describing. If you need the functionality of an innodb, then should you first check the existence of the row, otherwise can you convert the table to a myisam table.

edit: if you need to check the existence of the row before the decision to insert or update, then would I advice you to use a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE adjustusers(IN pId int)
BEGIN
DECLARE userid int;
  select  count(id) into userid from users where id = pId;
  if userid = 1 then
   update users set id = pId where id = pId;
  else
   insert into users(id) values(pId);
  end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

A stored procedure is precompiled, just as a prepared statement. Hence no SQL injection problems and some more functionality and only one call to the database.

Comment: Then do you not have any other choice then checking for the existence of the row first: